# CSS Non-Positioned Boxes

Tags: html, css

So, I am reading through the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-rules) on W3 site, and I came across the use of the word "non-positioned" which I am having a hard time picturing.  Please see below use.

> Since a float is not in the flow, non-positioned block boxes created
>   before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float did not
>   exist. However, the current and subsequent line boxes created next to
>   the float are shortened as necessary to make room for the margin box
>   of the float.

My question is/are,

what is a non-positioned box in CSS context? Is it a box in normal-flow? Or a box that does not have style property position explicitly set?
What does the first paragraph up there mean?

I mean what does the spec. mean by the

"current and subsequent line-boxes created next to the float are shortened to make room for the margin box of the floated-box"

when the floated-box is OUT-OF-FLOW?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Do not ask multiple question in one question.

Comment: I need answers therefore i asked questions

Comment: @ahsanawan please put down some example code for better understand your question

Comment: I did not understand these lines and therefore i have not any example . i have given w3c link from where i read these lines to fully understand the floats.

Comment: I'm afraid that this isn't a valid question. We don't teach, we solve!

Answer (score 3):

Three paragraphs above the one you quote, it says "The following is an introduction to float positioning and content flow; the exact rules governing float behavior are given in the description of the 'float' property."

So it is worth noting that the language used in the quote is not as precise as is usually is in the CSS spec.

> what is a non-positioned box in CSS context?

Here it means a box of an element whose `position` property has the value `static` That is, it always true for `position:static` elements. However, the quote does not imply that it is *always* false for boxes with other `position` values.

> Is it a box in normal-flow?

It's similar. Normal flow contains boxes that are `position:static` and `position:relative` and which are not floated elements.

> Or a box that does not have style property position explicitly set?

Not necessarily. Elements are `position:static` by default, but could be explicitly set to `static` too.

> what does the spec. mean by the
>
> "current and subsequent line-boxes created next to the float are shortened to
>   make room for the margin box of the floated-box"

In a (say) div element, the text is laid out as a stack of line boxes. If there is an immediately preceding float, The `<div>` element will go "behind" the float. You can see this by, say, reducing the opacity of the float and putting a background-color on the div. But the text won't go behind the float, because the text goes in the line boxes, and the line boxes avoid the float. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fj70uhfw/).